# Invalid postback or callback argument error when button click - Beginner

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the following error;

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I added a columm, and added a button into it, When the button is fired the following C# code gets executed;

ASP.NET Code

```
    <Columns>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField /> Definitions here --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="AddToCart" 
      CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
```

C#

```
   protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender,GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "AddToCart")
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                // Retrieve the row that contains the button 
                // from the Rows collection.
                GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            }

        }
```

How do i get rid of this error;

I added `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8"/>` but the error is still there.
`

**UPDATE**

```
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdv" AutoGenerateColumns="True" OnSorting="sortRecord" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="HotelName" CellPadding="4" Width="746px">
    <Columns>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField /> Definitions here --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" 
      CommandName="AddToCart" 
      CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
      Text="Add to Cart" />
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do you add any control dynamically? Can you show the GridView opening tag as well?

Comment: I'm not too sure but could you try with AutoGenerateColumns set to false?

Comment: Are you using update panel?

Comment: In page load set IsPostBack property.

Comment: I've never had much luck with the RowCommand/Template Field combo.  Check my answer for a way I know works. Your way can work if you remove it from a template field, and use an asp:ButtonField.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually find myself using is a buttons OnClick events instead of the GridViewRowCommand.  It's easier to work with for the most part.  So your ASP would look like;

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gdv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSorting="sortRecord"    AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="HotelName" CellPadding="4" Width="746px">
    <Columns>
      <%-- <asp:BoundField /> Definitions here --%>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:Button ID="AddButton" runat="server" OnClick="AddButton_Click" Text="Add to Cart" />
           </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And your c# would look like;

```
protected void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
}
```

Now in your code behind you can do anything you need to do with that row, and you know you'll be getting the row you want.

Hope this helps!